# Auto-completing words in any program

Tags: software-recommendation, text, productivity

I am looking for a program running on Mac OS X that allows the user to auto-complete words in any program.

For example, if the user types `soft`, the program could suggest `software` or `soften` in a dropbown menu, similarly to the auto-completion feature present in most IDEs:

[image]

Ideally:

- the program should allow the user to view the auto-completion options by using a keyboard shortcut.
- the options given by the program are listed by likelihood (e.g., using some language model)
- the program could be disabled in some programs.

Any price or license is fine.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- http://qr.ae/TbWFBy
- https://redd.it/6a6bas

Answer (score 2):

The Touch Bar integrates word prediction similar to iOS, which provides you with three word suggestions as you type. Tap a word to insert it. The more you type, the more the words filter. The screenshot shows when a new sentence is being started — type and the predictions finish your word.

> [image]

[Use the Touch Bar on your MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207055)

- Touch Bar word prediction is available by choosing View → Customise Touch Bar and enabling "Show typing suggestions" if they are not already available.

  [image]
- The options are listed with the most commonly used word in the middle and other common alternatives either side.
- You can disable word prediction by tapping the › button on the left of the suggestions.